# Class memeber name aliases in C++

Tags: c++, alias

I was wondering if we could have a class member be named by 2 names, for example my class has the variables `_width` and `_height` and I want my code to use `_width` by either using `_width` or `_rows`. I though I could use macros, but is there another way to do it in C++. Also is it a good practice to do so?
Thanks

Comment: It's possible but what's the gain of doing this?

Comment: It could of course be done with a preprocessor macro, but then _all_ instances of .e.g. `_rows` will be replaced by `_width`, and that might not be suitable everywhere. Also I wouldn't say it's good practice.

Comment: You can use reference. But keep in mind, it takes memory(unless compiler is smart).

Comment: `uint& _rows() { return _width; }` would be one way. But that doesn't gain anything to you.

Comment: In my code I'm using 2D arrays, so I want to be able to use both in case I used one by mistake not to have any problems when doing so

Comment: "use both in case I used one by mistake" ?? Isn't it easier to make sure you don't make that mistake than to write unnecessary code to  hide the mistake?

Comment: Compilers are awfully smart nowadays, @KAction. Usually smarter than us!

Comment: As far as I know, compilers are not allowed to reorder struct members. Wiping member out is even worse, is not it, @Cody Gray?

Comment: You said a "reference". How does that require reordering struct members or wiping them out?

Comment: Reference is just pointer in disgue. So it takes exactly `sizeof(void *)` memory. Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/5334967. On my machine, 16 vs 8. @CodyGray

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous union?

```
class two_names
{
  union
  {
    int width;
    int columns;
  };
};
```

In C++11 you can even put non PODs in there. Just be sure you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class StrangeOne {
  int _width, _height;
  int &_rows;
public:
  StrangeOne(int width,int height):
    _width(width),
    _height(height),
    _rows(_width)
  {
  };
};
```